# How to spawn java gui swing application using TCL code

Tags: java, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have an java swing application, application contains swing menus,  I need to test this java swing application using TCL code, like expect package communicate other process like telnet, ssh similar way the communication is possible with java swing application process using TCL code?

Comment: Why would you want to use TCL for this?

Comment: Testing a GUI app? That's… not easy. The problem is that you can't just squirt a recorded script into them because there are too many things that vary whatever you try.

Answer (score 2):

There's a program called [Android](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1691) (no, *not* the mobile device operating system! It predates that.) which allows an X11 GUI to be tested from Tcl. GUIs on other platforms are probably testable using it via VNC. Be aware that testing a GUI is *much* more difficult than testing a command-line application; things like weird behavior of window managers and tiny differences in fonts will be the total bane of your life.

That wiki page points to [here](https://sites.google.com/site/alosttclpkg/Home/android.tgz) for its download link, but I've not checked if that works or is buildable. (It does at least download for me, and appears to include *some* documentation…)

---

Alternatively, since you're automating testing of a Java GUI you look at [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), which you should be able to drive from [JTcl](https://jtcl.kenai.com/) (which is a Tcl interpreter written in Java, as opposed to the “standard” one written in C).